# Get policy value from chrome manage storage in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gpo

I am writing a browser extension and need to be able to configure it over mass deployment.
I'm trying to use chrome manage storage to do so, and cannot figure out why it is not working.
I did a schema.json, embed it into my extension. Load this extension into chrome and not getting any error. Then I configure a new entry on my macOS with the following command :

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome.extensions.*extensionId* IsIncognito -boolean true
```

Now I can see my policy showing up below my extension name in chrome://policy so I guess everything is ok. But when I try to get the policy from the extension service worker with the following code :

```
browser.storage.managed.get(null).then(t => console.log(t))
```

I get an empty object. Anyone has any idea about what I'm doing wrong ?

Edit: add extension id to avoid confusion to *defaults* command line.